# How to send image and more key value in http POST in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, laravel

[image: Working postman call]I have one API call where I provide image and other key values.
Everything works fine when I do it with POSTMAN. I select formData and add an image along with other key values.
But when I do the same in Angular it does not work.
every field get stored in the table except the image part.

My angular code is below

```
onFileSelected(event) {
    this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
  }

create(){
    var data ={};
    const fd = new FormData();

    fd.append('image',this.selectedFile,this.selectedFile.name);
    Object.keys(this.productForm.controls).forEach(key => {
      data[key] = this.productForm.get(key).value;
    });

    data["image"] = fd;
    this.spinner.show();
    this._service.post(Constant.createProduct,data).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res);
      this.spinner.hide();
    },
    error=>{
      this.spinner.hide();
    });
  }
```

I have also added a screenshot of the postman body which is working but not angular code.

This is backend service code in Laravel.

```
public function createProduct(Request $req){
        // 'name', 'preferred_chamber' ,'profile_picture_1','profile_picture_2','address', 'zone','note','google_location', 'list_number',  'phone_number', 'phone_number_2'
        
        
        $p=new Product();
        $p->name=$req->name;
        $p->brand_name=$req->brand_name;
        $p->mrp=$req->mrp;
        $p->cost_price=$req->cost_price;
        $p->unit=$req->unit;
        $p->weight=$req->weight;
        $p->qty=$req->qty;
        $p->inventory_qty=$req->inventory_qty;
        $p->category=$req->category;
         $p->reorder_qty=$req->reorder_qty;
          $p->product_desc=$req->product_desc;
           $p->inventory_type=$req->inventory_type;
        
        //upload profile picture
        if ($req->hasFile('image')) {
            $pp1_name=time().".jpg";
            $pp1 = request()->file('image')->move("/home/u481243053/domains/freelanceglobal.tech/public_html/sk_uploads", $pp1_name);
            $p->image= "http://freelanceglobal.tech/sk_uploads/".$pp1_name;
        }
        
        $p->save();
        
        return response()->json(['product'=>$p]);

    }
```

Comment: you have pass image as blob value or base64 encode value to server.

Comment: Do you add the header `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`?

Comment: @yazantahhan yes I have added that header.

Comment: What is the response error?

Comment: @yazantahhan no response error. I will attach the service code also

Comment: @aviboy2006 I have added the backend code you can see.

Comment: Try this way to achieve image upload in Angular https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-image-upload-easy-with-angular-1ed14cb2773b/

Comment: hello, can you provide the request body using Chrome DevTools > Network , and select the api call please ? just to see if your request body is really working with the right headers or not .. because it maybe that there is a HttpInterceptor or something which is blocking the formData to pass correctly with the right header.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an image then you shoud send FormData to request.

```
create(){
    const fd = new FormData();
 
    fd.append('image',this.selectedFile,this.selectedFile.name);
    Object.keys(this.productForm.controls).forEach(key => {
        fd.append(key,this.productForm.get(key).value);
    });

    this.spinner.show();
 
    this._service.post(Constant.createProduct,fd).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res);
      this.spinner.hide();
    },
    error=>{
      this.spinner.hide();
    });
}
```